# Android : Is it a good practise to extend PreferenceActivity to provide settings for my app

Tags: android, security, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Android app for which i would like to provide a settings screen extending PreferenceActivity. But I heard about a security vulnerability [Fragment Injection](http://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection/#.U2u8_KI2mOw) related with PreferenceActivity. I didn't understand the vulnerability completely.

Can anybody please tell me whether it is safe to use PreferenceActivity?

How badly affect my app, if I make use of PreferenceActivity?. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like the answer is contained in the linked article in the "The Fix" part ;-)

Comment: And in the "The Vulnerability" says "...can invoke any exported PreferenceActivity class...", So If you declare the activity as android:exported="false", i suppose you will not have problems.

Comment: Yeah, that's only with exported activities, so will depends on your app requirements. Anyways, I'd avoid using it if isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Could you pls recommend any solution that can be used instead of preference activity? In my app, which is like an account manager app, I do want to provide options to set a security lock pin for app, add/remove users, etc.

Comment: Here a is link describing the issue https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188427